# tcp server in python not handling multiple clients

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp

I need a TCP server to run on a Raspberry Pi that will allow multiple simultaneous client connections, process requests, allow clients to disconnect gracefully, and continue to listen forever. I found some code on an older post here that is close but has a few problems I cannot find a solution for.   The server script is:

```
import socket,threading

TIP   = '192.168.99.161'
TPORT = 3006
BUFFER_SIZE = 20

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,socket):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.socket = socket
        print "[+] New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)


    def run(self):    
        print "Connection from : "+ip+":"+str(port)
        clientsock.send("\nRPI02\n")
        data = "111"
        eof=False
        while len(data):
            data = clientsock.recv(20)
            for c in data:
                print ("%02X"%(ord(c)))
                if(c == 'z'):
                eof=True
            if(eof):
                # simulated packet:            
                clientsock.send("packet was processed.")
                eof = False

        print "%s:%d disconnected"%(ip,port)

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 9999

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

tcpsock.bind((TIP,TPORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(4)
    print "\nListening for incoming connections..."
    (clientsock, (ip, port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    newthread = ClientThread(ip, port,clientsock)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()

tcpsock.shutdown(sock.SHUT_RDWR)
tcpsock.close()
```

If I run one client, I can process data (send many bytes), with no problem.

The expectation of this system is that I don't expect to ever have more than two clients connected. When a client connects, it will send 3-4 bytes of request data, and once it receives an answer, it will disconnect (another Pi on the client end).

I ran a test with two client windows, one sending '123', the other sending 'abc'. Sending a 'z' from a client gets a server message confirming a processed packet.

Here's the test run:

```
mpi@RPI01 ~/iorelay $ python erc-test.py

Listening for incoming connections...
[+] New thread started for 192.168.99.99:64351

Listening for incoming connections...
Connection from : 192.168.99.99:64351
31
32
33
7A
[+] New thread started for 192.168.99.99:64361

Listening for incoming connections...
Connection from : 192.168.99.99:64361
61
62
63
7A
31
61
62
63
61
62
63
192.168.99.99:64361 disconnected
192.168.99.99:64361 disconnected
```

I see several problems here:

1. The second (or last) client to connect can send data all day long, with the fake-packet response from the server. All previous clients may send a few more bytes (one in this case) but eventually the server stops receiving from them.
2. I disconnected the first client, and no disconnect message appeared. When I closed the second one, I printed two disconnect messages with the same client port number.
3. I don't understand the 't.join' loop after the main while() - what would this be for? If I comment this out it doesn't seem to change anything.
4. Even with the shutdown() call at the end, when I close this script with ctl-z the socket evidently hangs. When I run the script again, it complains the socket is in use.
5. How do I clean up all the hung sockets in Linux? (Rasbian on Pi)

Thanks for any help on this - still learning Python...

Comment: There are a few interesting things - 1) Why do you say data is not received from first client? It's not clear - can you also post your client program? I believe a number of your issues can be explained if I try to run some of those myself and see what exactly is the issue.

Comment: I stop seeing the print statement for each byte received, so I assume the clientsock.recv() is not returning anything (not sure).  There is no client program - I open multiple command windows and run telnet into the python server.  You should be able to see the no-receive problem in the first telnet session once you connect a second one...

Comment: May be you should paste the client code. Your last 'disconnected line is a surprise', So I'd like to run it myself and see what's really the issue.